# How to calculate base value in modular exponentiation

Tags: rsa

If you have $a^b \bmod n = c$, and $b,n,$ and $c$ values are given, is it possible to find a value for $a$ within a given range?

So is it possible to find $a$ in $a^{2051} \bmod 3149=636$ knowing a lies in between $1900$ and $2000$?

Comment: For your practical application of this (?) How large are n and the range? Is n usually a prime?

Comment: Hmm... If you know that "a lies in between 1900  and 2000" you can simply try all these values, can't you?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: consider that as the problem of deciphering $c$ in textbook RSA encryption with public key $(n,b)$.

Comment: It's not given that $n = pq$, though...

Comment: @fkraiem: yes. But one step of Fermat factors $n=3149$. Compute $r=\lceil\sqrt n\,\rceil=57$, $p=57-\sqrt{r^2-n}=47$, $q=2r-p=67$. I'd rather do this than try $a$ blindly. Of course I got that you where joking, me too.